# what happens to bounty not awarded in 7days?

Tags: support, bounty, unanswered-questions

For example, my question doesn't receive the right answer for 7 days? Does the (50 bounty) will be added again on my reputation or it will go somewhere?

Answer (score 6):

From [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances.

You pay the bounty to get higher visibility for your question for a week. It doesn't guarantee an answer.

Comment: that's pretty bad, it should just be a reward for anyone who can answer your question not payment to promote a question

Comment: @Pixelomo Placing a bounty can't guarantee that it will get an answer. It's non-refundable and time-limited to discourage people from abusing it, and to encourage people to exhaust every other avenue before placing a bounty.

Comment: there should at least be a bounties tab on the homepage so open bounties are easily found

Comment: @Pixelomo It's the Featured tab at the top.

Comment: @Pixelomo Now I wonder how many people have struggled to find that because of the odd naming choice.

Comment: yeah think bounties would be a better name